# Java regex match number of times substring/char appears in string

Tags: java, regex, formal-languages

I'm writing a program to recognize valid (as defined by the user) expressions, and I need to be able to match the number of times a specific character matches in one part with another. For example, if I'm using the pq system, in

```
(some number of dashes)p-q(some number of dashes)
```

the number of dashes before the p has to match the number of dashes after the q (for any number of dashes) for it to be a valid expression.

I'm trying to make this robust/generalizable (user-defined rules, you can use * instead of -, you can make it so that you need double the amount of dashes after the q, etc), I was thinking adding some special text (like `-(%%n%%)p-q-(%%n%%)` where anything having `(%%n%%)` after it has to appear exactly 'n' times), but before I do that are there any built-in regex capabilities/reasonably simple fixes or am I going to need to start with my %%'s?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: Looking at my problem again, the better way to word it is that I essentially need to figure out a way to mark two (or possibly more) substrings (in a general way) to verify that they match. I have some degree of flexibility in how I do it (not solely limited to regex), but the rest of the system uses regex so something that doesn't conflict/massively overcomplicate what I'd need to do to get it to work would be ideal.

Comment: Editted to better explain the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your problem right, regex will be not sufficient, as you are trying to catch string generated by non-regular grammar. Some simple [pushdown automaton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) should help here.

Comment: I updated the question but I'm not sure if answers get updated with edits. I'm not solely limited to regex to define what a "valid expression" is, I have essentially all of the java libraries to help parse expressions (I can say "oh replace any string '%%word%%' in the expression with some corresponding predefined constant"). I'm not sure if that helps, but I'll definitely look into the link, so thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 0):

If you were to allow the user to select the number of before and after,
the regex would be trivial.

In general, this is a way to construct a variable regex for before and after.

```
 ( -{1,10} )  # (1)
 p-q
 \1           # Backreference to capture group 1
```

If you wanted to construct a string dynamically, it would be something like this
`"(-{1," + vNum + "})p-q\\1"`
You could also add a quantifier on the back end like this
`"(-{1," + vNum + "})p-q\\1{" + nFactor + }"`

You can change the quantifier's form to get whatever you need *{2}*, or a range *{1,3}* etc...

Remember though, the capture group contains a subset of what you expect on the back end.